# How to call static block from Category Layout Update XML Magento 2?

Tags: layout, magento-2.1

I am trying to call a static block in category page after category products.
I have added a below code in category design layout update xml but nothing is displaying.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="search-block" after="category.products">
<arguments>
<argument name="57" xsi:type="string">search-block</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Display mode is staticblock and products.

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using luma theme or any other, select the theme and save by below layout update. I used `contact-us-info` block for reference you can replace by your block id.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>

     <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">contact-us-info</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Have added reference screen-shoot below.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="search-block" after="category.products">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">search-block</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

argument name needs to be `block_id` where static block id is `search-block`

Comment: Hi
I have tried below but its not working